# Phalcon Assets Filter to obfuscate JS code

Tags: javascript, obfuscation, phalcon

Is there an existing Phalcon Filter to obfuscate JS code? I've been googling but without result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, there isn't. Use the Jsmin filter for minification, but that doesn't change variable and class names, so it doesn't obfuscate your code.

```
$manager
    ->collection('myscripts')
    ->setTargetPath('scripts.js')
    ->setTargetUri('/production/scripts.js')
    ->addJs('somescript.js')
    ->addJs('someotherscript.js')
    ->join(true)
    // Use the built-in Jsmin filter
    ->addFilter(new Phalcon\Assets\Filters\Jsmin());
```

According to the docs, this "Deletes the characters which are insignificant to JavaScript. Comments will be removed. Tabs will be replaced with spaces. Carriage returns will be replaced with linefeeds. Most spaces and linefeeds will be removed."

**--- edit ---**

There's always the possibility to use Gulp instead of Phalcon's Asset pipeline. There are prerequisites like Node.js, but I found it very useful as there are countless of filters available for Gulp, including an obfuscation filter and many more.

See [Gulp documentation](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'm already using Jsmin, but for more protection against some thieves there I'm trying to obfuscate the all JS scripts, I'll wait a little bit more, if no one knows, I guess I'll have to develop my own filter for that.

Comment: You can try [closure compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/) as a .jar file run from console.

Comment: Gulp was the perfect choice for me, I'm using it with Phalcon's cache, it's perfect. Thank you :)